# Download multiple files in parallel like whats app in Android

Tags: android, service, android-service, whatsapp

***I already know that using Services/Intent services we download multiple files*** in background. But this problem have one more complexity to solve.

***I have to download multiple videos/images in different activities in parallel like whats app***. I have seen in whats app that we can start download and then we can moves on different screens or press home button etc. But when we move back on that screen again the downloading is still continue with and showing the updated progress.

[image: Sample app have 4 screens all with downloading option]

Like above there is 4 activities and user started downloading of ABC.mp4 on activity and A and then moves on to Activity B. Then moves on to C and started downloading of video/image. If user moves back on to the A and I want to show the progress of that ABC.mp4 file that how much downloaded and same case for the other activities.

Please let me know to you Services or any other way to do, so I can update the UI as well with the updated value of the downloading file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about AsyncTasks executed on executer? Produce one for each file to download.

Comment: @michael yeah you are right but how to maintain that on which activity which async task for which file and then show it's progress as well.

Answer (score 2):

Well here's my piece of advice:

I did the same thing but with Pdf files a while a ago. First you need to choose a good Http client library to perform the downloads and forget about all the issues related to the downloads that you'll have if you perform this operations by yourself. I recommend you use the [Ion librabry](https://github.com/koush/ion) has a lot of useful features like cancel the downloads, attach callbacks to have an eye in the download progress, known if the download succeded, failed, etc.

Second, you obviously need a Service running in background, always, you can do this by making your own service, and It's very important that the Service process name in the android manifest is like `android:name="com.company.app.services.MyService"` and not like `android:name=":MyRemoteService"` doing so you'll make sure that the service will be running in background all the time (keep in mind that the OS can and will kill the service if It's neccesary, but the service will be restarted when the resources will made available again).

Third, to keep all the views, custom views, activities, fragments, etc. that display those files updated, you need trigger `BroadcastReceiver`s from your Service. Keep in mind that doing so you can't use the `LocalBroadcastReceiver`, because your Service has its own process indipendent from your application.

[image]

Keep in mind that:

1) Theres no need to explicitly use an Activity, you can register your broadcasts anywhere where you see It fit. A RecyclerAdapter (most likely), a Fragment, or an Activity.

2) The communication App/Service is done through `Intents` so all data that you send to and from the Service must be `Serializable`.

3) You can use several different types of broadcast each one for differents situations (error, fail, success, progress, etc.) or you can use only one an send a `enum` that describe this kind of status through the Bundle of the Intent when you fire the broadcasts from your service

Hope this helps you, If you have any doubt, let me know.

Comment: I'll attach an image with the basic arch